# Cannot find my minecraft saves

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I apologize if this is a duplicate question (please provide me a link if there is an answer already out there).  I cannot find my saves for minecraft.

1. One post says to look here "C:\Users{myname}\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe"  I do not have a Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe folder
2. Another post says look for saves folder in the installation folder. 
   For me that is C:\games\minecraft.  There is no saves folder here.
3. Another post says in App data.  for me that's C:\Users{myname}\AppData\Local.minecraft.  There is no .minecraft folder here.
4. I did find this folder.  C:\Users{myname}\AppData\Roaming.minecraft but there's no worlds here.

I'm totally lost.  I have 4 worlds created.  My changes to the worlds are saved.

Where are my worlds saved?  Btw, I'm running windows 10.

Comment: @Virusbomb Not sure how its a duplicate.  as I stated in #3 I do not have %APPDATA%\.minecraft\ folder.  Html rendering doesnt seem like slash + dot.

Comment: @Nolonar While the question may be slightly different the answer is applicable to all platforms. It has windows mentioned specifically.

Comment: @Virusbomb. I noticed afterwards, that's why I deleted my comment.

Comment: @tatmanblue There is an alternate solution in the top answer on that question that shows another way of finding the folder.

Comment: According to the [**official site**](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/1480874-where-are-minecraft-files-stored-), it should be under `%appdata%\.minecraft` If there is no such folder, you might want to contact support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found it.  I followed the link @Virusbomb shared.

I could not find the menu choice "Mods and Texture Packs". I did not have this menu on the launcher screen nor the main game screen.  Not sure whats up with that.  (After I found a way to find my folders, I did find navigating "options | resource packs" I had a button that would open the resource folder which is the same thing, I think)

Anyways, here's how I found my saves.

I chose my world, clicked edit.  That gave me a choice to "open folder".

This put me in "D:\documents\public\minecraft worlds\saves{myworld}"

I do not know how I configured minecraft to use that folder.  However, that is where my worlds are saved.

Thnx
Matt